# Why does using a struct in Pallet storage create a crate-private leak?

Tags: storage

I am attempting to use a custom struct in a map which needs to be stored.

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
pub(super) struct Amendment<AccountId> {
        pub statement: Vec<u8>,
        pub owners: Vec<AccountId>,
}

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn declaration_map)]
pub(super) type Declarations<T: Config> = StorageMap
<
_,
Blake2_128Concat,
<T as Config>::AccountId,
Amendment<<T as pallet::Config>::AccountId>,
ValueQuery
>;
```

It is giving me this error:

[image]

Is there a way to make it public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#[pallet::storage]` creates a `pub fn amendment() -> Amendment<_> { .. }` which leaks `Amendment<_>` which is according to your definition a narrower public scope.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/storage.rs#L288

`pub(super) Amendment` must become `pub Amendment` to resolve this.